# Which property of Scala's type-system make it Turing-complete?

Tags: scala, types, language-design, type-systems, turing-complete

Scala uses a type-system based on System F ω, which is normally said to be strongly normalizing. Strongly normalizing implies non-Turing completeness.

Nevertheless, Scala's type-system is Turing-complete.

Which changes/additions/modifications make Scala's type-system Turing-complete compared to the formal algorithms and systems?

Comment: Have links/references? (For spectators, like me :-)

Comment: The fact that System F is strongly normalizing implies that System F is not Turing complete. It does not imply that its type system isn't. And in fact it has been shown that [typechecking an unrestricted System F is undecidable](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.6.6483)

Comment: @sepp2k -- yikes, the worst thing about Turing-completeness and it's got that.

Comment: @sepp2k, the result you cite holds only for undecorated lambda terms.  If explicit types are given for lambda-abstracted type variables, and if type abstraction is explicit in the source code, then type checking  System F is a snap---my students do it as a homework assignment.

Comment: @pst http://michid.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/scala-type-level-encoding-of-the-ski-calculus/ ; [messages 6,7](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-debate/browse_thread/thread/7a4c67fc76da4d1f/) ; http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7698  
http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/simple-ski-combinator-calculus-in-scalas-type-system/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a comprehensive answer but the reason is that you can define **recursive** types.

I've asked similar questions before ([about what a non-Turing complete language might look like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492188/what-are-the-practical-limitations-of-a-non-turing-complete-language-like-coq)). The answers were of the form: *a Turing complete language must support either arbitrary looping or recursion*. Scala's type system supports the latter

Comment: Recursive types exist in most languages, including Java and Pascal. Any type that refers to itself (like a linked list) is recursive. You need a way to perform computation at the type level, such as type application. In Scala, you have type members and partial type application in type aliases.

Comment: I meant recursive types in the sense of the peano encoding: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/ using `type`, not `class` or `trait`. I thought that was reasonably obvious given the context. Like I said, I am echoing here, what I have been told about turing completeness.

Comment: [Recursive types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type) can be used to encode numbers like you say, but they're not enough for Turing completeness. What you want is a way to compute, in this case using type application (which in turn uses substitution). Scala's type members make it somewhat easy, though Java performs similar substitutions for generics.